# How to install a 3rd Party Plugin Deluge Windows

Tags: python

This was very confusing for me. In order to save you all some trouble this is how you do it.

1. You need to already have python installed so that it can be called from the command prompt.
2. Download your 3rd party plugin as a zip. ex. [AutoRemovePlus](https://github.com/omaralvarez/deluge-autoremoveplus)
3. Extract that plugin to a folder.
4. Shift right click in the folder and click "Open command window here"
5. Now run "python setup.py bdist_egg" - this will created a folder within that folder called dist.
6. Open dist, in there you will now have a file called "AutoRemovePlus-0.5-py2.7.egg" it might be 2.6 , make sure you rename it to whatever version of python your deluge uses. [Version Check](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#PythonVersion)
7. Now follow the instructions to install that egg file as you would any other deluge plugin. [Deluge Plugin Install](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins#InstallingPluginEggs)
8. You should now be able to use the plugin.

Comment: [Self-answering is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) but this isn't the way to do it. Please edit your _question_ to contain the question you want to answer and put your _answer_ as an answer below, where you have currently added a comment.

Comment: Also, this is off-topic because it isn't a programming question. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be a better place for it.

Comment: Ok I will move it to there, it was kinda python related so I wasn't sure. Thanks

Comment: I have moved this to superuser, how do I del this?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit of searching and messing around since I know nothing about python but above is how I did it. If you have a better answer I am all ears.